# tmux: copy mode stops execution of shell command

Tags: execution, tmux, copy-mode

when i use the copy mode to scroll in my tmux version while some other program runs in this pane, execution seems to be halted until i return to "normal mode".
My tmux version is 1.8.

Is there an option to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to change this. Later versions will exit copy mode if you don't use it for a while (180 seconds IIRC) to stop programs blocking forever. 1.8 is very old.

Comment: damn, thanks for the information. yes thats due to the fact that i use anchient centos7..